# Compare two lists and increase the counter on a match with java streams

Tags: java, count, stream, compare

I have two lists. `list1` contains some citiys.

`list2` contains sub-lists. Each sub-list contains the countries already visited by a person (one sub-list = the countries visited by one person). In the example Person1 has traveld to Rom, Amsterdam and Vienna, Person2 to Amsterdam, Barcelona and Milan ...

I would like to know how many people have already been to the countries in the first list. There should be no double counting. So if Person1 has already been to two countries from `list1`, it should only be counted once.

I would like to implement this with Java Streams. Does anyone know how I can do this?

```
list1 = ["Barcelona", "Milan", "Athens"];
list2 = [["Rom", "Amsterdam", "Vienna"], ["Amsterdam", "Barcelona", "Milan"], ["Prais", "Athens"], ["Istanbul", "Barcelona", "Milan", "Athens"]];

//The expected result for this example is: 3
//Both lists already result from a stream (Collectors.toList())
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have tried a lot but nothing that comes close to working.

Comment: Then show us what you tried so far

Comment: I don't see where is your solution! even if it doesn't work with you, we could look and help. 
But I guess if you understand this example in the link below, it will help you to solve your  problem 
https://www.javaprogramto.com/2020/07/nested-lists-with-streams-in-java-8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```java
    private static final List<String> CITIES = List.of("Barcelona", "Milan", "Athens");
    private static final List<List<String>> VISITED_CITIES = List.of(
            List.of("Rome", "Amsterdam", "Vienna"),
            List.of("Amsterdam", "Barcelona", "Milan"),
            List.of("Paris", "Athens"),
            List.of("Instabul", "Barcelon", "Milan", "Athens")
    );

    public static void main(String... args) {
        var count = VISITED_CITIES
                .stream()
                .flatMap(visited -> visited.stream().filter(CITIES::contains))
                .distinct()
                .count();
        System.out.println(count);
    }
```

With this iteration you will get the expected result of 3. However you can modify your code to also collect into a `Map` that will show frequencies (if you remove the `distinct` intermediate step), something like this:

```java
        var count = VISITED_CITIES
                .stream()
                .flatMap(visited -> visited.stream().filter(CITIES::contains))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `mapToInt()` and `sum()` function.

```java
List<String> list1 = List.of("Barcelona", "Milan", "Athens");
        List<List<String>> list2 = List.of(List.of("Rom", "Amsterdam", "Vienna"),
                                           List.of("Amsterdam", "Barcelona", "Milan"),
                                           List.of("Prais", "Athens"),
                                           List.of("Istanbul", "Barcelona", "Milan", "Athens"));
int result = list2.stream().mapToInt(person -> person.stream().anyMatch(list1::contains) ? 1 : 0).sum();
```

What I do here is create a stream of all persons and then map each person to either 1 or 0 depending on if any of their visited countries is contained in list1.

This is identical with the following for-loop example:

```java
int result = 0;
for (List<String> person : list2)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (String visited : person)
    {
        if (list1.contains(visited))
        {
            i = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    result += i;
}
```